# Prove that \begin{eqnarray} \lim\limits_{p\rightarrow +\infty }||f||_{L^p}=||f||_{L^\infty}. \end{eqnarray}

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to prove this. We are told that $(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$ is a measure space, and $\mu(X)=1$. We are also told that $f$ is a bounded, measurable function on $X$.

So how can I prove that
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim\limits_{p\rightarrow +\infty }||f||_{L^p}=||f||_{L^\infty}.
\end{eqnarray}
Any help please?

Comment: Can you prove an inequality?  One side $\le$ the other?